# Javascript: How to change href for all <area> tag ID's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tooltip

I am trying to do the code below but for each ID of my areas. I have tried using loops but I cant work out how to change the HREF for each ID according to the alt tag if that makes sense...

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function doSomething(getID){
var a = document.getElementById('cp1');
var b = getID.alt;
a.href = b + ".html";
};
```

**HTML:**

```
<area id="cp1" class="jTip" shape="rect" coords="0,77,41,123"  alt="Place1" onmouseover="javascript:doSomething(this);" href="javascript:doSomething(this);"> 
<area id="cp2" class="jTip" shape="rect" coords="0,122,41,171" alt="Place2" onmouseover="javascript:doSomething(this);" href="javascript:doSomething(this);">  
<area id="cp3" class="jTip" shape="rect" coords="0,220,41,170" alt="Place3" onmouseover="javascript:doSomething(this);" href="javascript:doSomething(this);">
```

The code works for the first ID but I want it to work for all ID's that relate to the area tag rather than me just putting each ID with a new variable and then changing the HREF for each id.

I have over 60 areas or ID's but I really need to simplify the code if its possible.

If anyone could help me, this would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName), which returns a [*NodeList*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) you can then iterate over.

```
var areas = document.getElementsByTagName('area'), // get
    i;

for (i = 0; i < areas.length; ++i)                 // loop
    areas[i].href = areas[i].alt + '.html';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var areas = document.getElementByTagName("area");
for (var i = 0; i < areas.length; ++ i) {
    var h = areas[i].alt;
    areas[i].href = h + ".html";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of getElementById, you can use getElementsByTagName('area').  This will give you an array of all the elements with tag name "area".

Comment: thank you for your reply:) Getting tag name is far better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply, **your answer works perfectly!** I have also found an alternative after some trial and error. Spent a few days trying to google ways of doing it prior to sending the question.

```
var tag = document.getElementsByClassName('jTip');
for (var i = 0; i < tag.length; ++i) {

var a = document.getElementById(tag[i].id);
var b = getID.alt;
a.href = b + ".html";

}
};
```

Your way is far better & thanks for the quick response. Question is solved!

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow. If an answer was helpful and or solved your question, don't forget to upvote it and or select it as the chosen answer. This lets the community know the question has been dealt with and helps any future visitor with the same problem. The help topic about this can be found [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

you are getting `this` inside the `doSomething` function so you already have the element so just assign the values

```
function doSomething(element){
element.href = element.alt + ".html";
};
```